# Pre-Populate selectCheckBoxes

Tags: apex, visualforce

How do we go about pre-populating selectCheckBoxes? I want to save the state of which boxes are checked for when the user comes back to the form. My idea is to save the list of selected checkBox values and then check for that list when ever the checkBoxes are rendered in the future.

I'm creating my selectCheckBoxes in my controller like so:

```
public List<SelectOption> getcolumnChoices(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    // get all fields in Opportunty object
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get('Opportunity').getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for (Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()) {
        schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();        
        options.add(new SelectOption(dfield.getName(), dfield.getLabel()));
    }
    return options;
}
```

However, I'm not finding any kind of option to pass the SelectOption class a flag that the option should be selected. Am I looking in the wrong place?

For good measure, here is my relevant page code:

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedFields}" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="makeRows">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!columnChoices}" />
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedFields` is the variable in your controller that holds the values. If you want to set some defaults, you can do it in the constructor for your controller.

Comment: doh. i thought i was doing that, but after further investigation, my process of saving selectedFields wasn't correct. Once I fixed that - and selectedFields saved its value - the checkBoxes populated wonderfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're looking in the wrong place.  The `SelectOption` class holds the available values (your `columnChoices` variable) , and has some additional parameters for controlling whether something is selectable or not, e.g. a "Choose Fields" in a drop down might not be selectable.

The values for what selected or going to be either a list of strings, in your case the `selectedFields` variable.  If you want it to start with specific values, just put them in there when the page loads.